# Eliminate duplicate elements fetched from a table and inserted into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates

I ran over many questions in stackoverflow but none seemed to help me. I know there are many like this post, but I'm in need of help.

I'm trying to get a table's column into array and then I'm trying to remove duplicate elements. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9sbPg/2/) jsfiddle illustrates the situation. Here's the code:

```
//sorry for the language 
var days2 = ["Pazartesi", "Salı", "Pazartesi", "Çarşamba"];
var days = jQuery.makeArray($(".dersprg tr td:nth-child(6)"));

//the function works just fine on days2 array, but not on days array
function eliminateRepeat(array){
  var i, j;
  for(i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
      for(j=i+1 ; j < array.length ; j++){
          if(array[i] == array[j])
              array.splice(j,1);
       }
  }
}
eliminateRepeat(days);
$(days).clone().appendTo(document.getElementById("test"));
```

The table I used is sort of huge for here, you'd better see it from jsfiddle.

Note: I used many functions written as answers to other questions, none seemed to work for me. I wrote my own function finally, which works fine on a string based array, however it still can not make the job done with a **selected html element based** array.

Comment: what's it doing wrong? I can't tell.

Comment: I would say its bad form to modify an array inside a for loop. It would actually be easier to check for duplicates as your building the array in the first place.

Comment: How would you do that @Rob from a table like that? I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the function works just fine on days2 array, but not on days array

Yes, since there are no duplicates in the elements list. There may be some with the same text, but they are different nodes and do not equal with the `==` operator. You would need to change

```
if(array[i] == array[j])
```

to

```
if($(array[i]).text() == $(array[j]).text())
```

---

Btw, your `splice` removes one element from the array so that all indizes change. Yet, by going to the next index you are going to jump over one item. Use `array.splice(j--,1);`

Comment: what makes them different nodes? What attribute is different? Thank you for the fast answer by the way:)

Comment: They are two distinct instances. They may have the same markup, but they are not the same objects.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why it did not work on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9sbPg/4/) example :( I't reduces most of them but the result is not a desired one. The original table source is [this](http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb=BLG) in case you need it.

Comment: if you end up with more than two duplicates in a row in the array your splice method will fail. It would be better to create a DistinctArray in the elimination function and return it.